# Custom Element getter/setter not working when inside module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, web-component

I have an issue with my custom element where I cannot make getter and setter work when inside a module.

```
<head>
    <script type="module">
        class Foo extends HTMLElement {
            get prop() {
                alert('get called')
                return 'somevalue'
            }

            set prop(value) {
                alert('set called');
                this._prop = value;
            }
        }
        customElements.define('foo-elem', Foo);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <foo-elem></foo-elem>
    <script>
        let foo = document.querySelector('foo-elem');
        foo.prop = 2; // <- this does not trigger the setter
    </script>
</body>
```

When I remove the `type="module"` from the script everything is working fine. Is there a way I can import (es6 imports) that way I declare every components in separate files ?

Comment: seems to be working fine. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @MrKhan I've addded a more complete example

Comment: you dont need to use type module to include your script from other files. It should work like normal scripts.

Comment: @MrKhan But then I am putting variables in global scope when I don't want to. I also have multiple import inside the customElement and these are es6 imports so I need to have the file as a type module.

Comment: Just add type="module" into the other script as well it will allow acces to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue related to the loading sequence of your scripts.

Scripts with `type=module` are `defer` by default - meaning they are executed only when the document has finished parsing.

Your other plain `script` tag is not `defer` so it executed when it's encountered - so it's executed first, before you've defined your custom element and its getters/setters. The `module` script is executed afterwards once the browser has got to the end of the document.

`defer` scripts are however executed in the order they appear. So if you make the second script `defer` - either by adding the `defer` attribute, or by making it `type="module"` then the getters/setters will work as expected.